# No puedo cambiar de rama en git

Tags: git

Tengo un repositorio en git con dos ramas, master y develop, inicializo y clono mi repositorio pero al intentar cambiar a develop me amrca esto:

error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: probaste asi? git checkout "nombreDeLaRama a ir"

Comment: revisa las ramas tanto locales como remotas `git branch --all`. Si no tienes una rama develop en tu remoto (`remotes/origin/develop`) puede que necesites hacer `git fetch --all` para actualizar el remoto. Si la rama no existe en el remoto, tendrás que crearla con `git checkout -b develop`

Comment: git checkout <nombre de la rama>
switched to a new branch '<nombre de la rama>'

Answer (score 2):

Intenta primero sincronizar tu repositorio local con el remoto y luego cambiar de rama

```
git fetch
git checkout develop
```